# iCloud Keychain - view online

Tags: icloud, keychain

Is there any way of viewing the contents of your iCloud Keychain online? After a computer failure, I have no access to my keychain items!

I have another laptop running Snow Leopard, but it is not compatible with iCloud.

I have looked through the iCloud FAQs, but have found nothing useful:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, your iCloud Keychain can't be viewed online.** You need to access the iCloud Keychain service through OS X or iOS to be able to access it, which requires a compatible version of either.

Furthermore, the data is not stored within Documents & Data so you can't access it through iCloud Developer.