# How to remove Kaspersky icon on menu bar?

Tags: macos, applications, menu-bar

Downloaded the Kaspersky app just for fun and to give it go. It had a trial time so when the time was up, I simply just dragged the app into the trash can and then emptied it. However, the kaspersky "K" icon on the menu bar just won't go away.

It kept prompting me to update the app but I can't even update because I've already deleted it. It has the option for me to "quit" but when I restart, it appears again.

I've tried deleting the file over at library/applications support but it still won't go away.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official uninstallation tool for OS X:

- http://media.kaspersky.com/utilities/ConsumerUtilities/Uninstall_Kaspersky_Internet_Security.zip

Download and run this package to completely remove the app.

Comment: You just set a record for fastest answer (if there is such thing) - 20 seconds from edit to answer or 1 min 12 seconds from OP.

Comment: @Buscar [This](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127869/icloud-keychain-view-online/127870#127870) is still my fastest (33 seconds from OP asking the question; Ask Different record)

Comment: Since it is Trashed already, does the OP has to reinstall the kaspersky first?

Comment: @Buscar No, it's a standalone removal tool.